# How does Google Chrome determine URL patterns for Site Search?

Tags: google-search, url, search, google-chrome

I have recently started monitoring my site jujubuy.com on Google Webmasters Tools. I have added codes to generate JSON-LD based structured data for Sitelinks Searchbox. I've supplied correct URL pattern with necessary query parameters on my website's structured data.

I somehow assumed that Google Chrome might rectify the problem when Googlebot finds this data on my website. But, I didn't see any change in the incorrect behavior of Google Chrome. When I type something like this in Google Chrome address bar:

```
jujubuy.com buy transistor
```

It redirects me to an URL like this:

```
https://jujubuy.com/search?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=buy+transistors&submit_search=
```

Obviously, this URL is not correct and it results in a Page Not Found error. Does Chrome get this site search link patterns from a place where I can rectify it? My concern in not only for my own browser, but for any Google Chrome browsers, which are used by my website users.

Comment: Is this a documented Chrome feature? I don’t use Chrome, but I would have assumed that entering this in the address bar would result in showing the Google Search result page. I tried the query in Chromium and it works as expected: it shows the Google Search results.

Comment: Possibly because the site publishes an [OpenSearch description document](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#OpenSearch_description_document)

Comment: This just performs a normal Google search for me in Chrome as well. Have you, by chance, added a "search engine" to your Chrome browser?

Comment: It does google search for most of the sites. but for some sites it indeed searches the website for the given keywords (after domain name). I've see this difference. I am curious. Where does it know which website has a built in search feature and how it expects the parameters.